# Computing values of a column in dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider below two data frames (unequal length).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2016-10-08', '2016-11-08','2016-12-08','2017-01-08'], 'qty': [1,8,2,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2016-11-12', '2017-01-12'], 'factor': [2,3]})

>>> df1
         date  qty
0  2016-10-08    1
1  2016-11-08    8
2  2016-12-08    2
3  2017-01-08    4

>>> df2
         date  factor
0  2016-11-12       2
1  2017-01-12       3
```

I want to calculate a new column called `factored_quantity` in `df1` which is as below.

> Choose all the factor in `df2` whose dates are greater than the date in `df1` and multiple the `qty` by the same to arrive at `factored_qty`

So my final dataframe would look like

```
>>> df1
         date  qty      factored_qty
0  2016-10-08    1          6
1  2016-11-08    8          48
2  2016-12-08    2          6
3  2017-01-08    4          12
```

**Explanation:**

1. `2016-10-08` in `df1` is less than both `2016-11-12` and `2017-01-12` of `df2`. So multiply by factor `2*3*qty`
2. However, date `2016-12-08` in `df1` is greater than `2016-11-12` and less than `2017-01-12` of `df2`. So only multiply by factor `3*qty`

Most of what I have looked are related to
1. Merge two dataframe.
2. Compare two dataframe of equal length
3. Compare two dataframe of un-equal length

However, the current issue is related to computing a value based on collected (factors multiplied) value of another dataframe - where the foreign keys will not be equal.

Comment: what happens if the date in df1 > df2 ?

Comment: Default factor would be 1. So it would be multiplied by 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `date` dtype is valid datetime else use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then you can use [`pd.Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.0rc1/api/generated/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) and use [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:~:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how,that%20they%20have%20compatible%20shapes.) here to compare and build a boolean array for boolean indexing. Then use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), use [`np.prod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) to get product of the whole array.

```
mask = df1.date.to_numpy()[:,None] < df2.date.to_numpy() # `_.values` should be avoided instead use `_.to_numpy()`
it = iter(mask)

def mul(x):
    val = np.prod(df2.loc[next(it),'factor'])
    return x*val

df1['factored_qty'] = df1['qty'].map(mul)
df1
        date  qty  factored_qty
0 2016-10-08    1             6
1 2016-11-08    8            48
2 2016-12-08    2             6
3 2017-01-08    4            12
```

**OR**

```
mask = df1.date.to_numpy()[:,None] < df2.date.to_numpy()
l = [np.prod(df2.loc[idx,'factor']) for idx in mask]
     # df2.loc[idx,'factor'].prod()
df['factored_qty'] = df1.qty.mul(l)
```

Timeit analysis:

```
# My answer
In [163]: %%timeit
     ...: mask = df1.date.to_numpy()[:,None] < df2.date.to_numpy() # `_.values` should be avoided instead use `_.to_num
     ...: py()`
     ...: it = iter(mask)
     ...: 
     ...: def mul(x):
     ...:     val = np.prod(df2.loc[next(it),'factor'])
     ...:     return x*val
     ...: df1['factored_qty'] = df1['qty'].map(mul)
     ...:
     ...:
1.31 ms ± 28.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# Stef's answer.
In [164]: %%timeit
     ...: df1['factored_qty'] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2[df2.date>x.date].factor.cumprod().values[-1] * x.qty,axis=1)
     ...:
     ...:
3.65 ms ± 194 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#sammy's answer
In [180]: %%timeit
     ...: d = defaultdict(list)
     ...: #iterate through data and append factors that meet criteria
     ...: for (date1, qty), (date2, factor) in product(df1.to_numpy(),df2.to_numpy()) : 
     ...:     if date1 < date2 :
     ...:         d[(date1, qty)].append(factor)
     ...: outcome = {k:[s,np.prod((s,*v))] for (k,s),v in d.items()}
     ...: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(outcome, orient='index', columns=['qty','factored_qty']).reset_index()
     ...:
     ...:
1.49 ms ± 47.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the fastest solution for large dataframes but it works. We use `prod` on all rows of `df2` that meet the condition.

```
df1['factored_qty'] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2[df2.date>x.date].factor.prod() * x.qty,axis=1)
```

Result:

```
         date  qty  factored_qty
0  2016-10-08    1             6
1  2016-11-08    8            48
2  2016-12-08    2             6
3  2017-01-08    4            12
```

---

**Update**
For larger dataframes we can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html). We calculate the reverse `cumprod`, i.e. from last to first row. Unfortunately it becomes a bit convoluted if the last date in df2 is less then the last date in df1 as we have to add a sentinel to df2 (maximum date of df1 with factor 1) in this case.
This method is significantly faster than Ch3steR's and sammywemmy's solutions.

```
df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df1.date)),
                    df2.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df2.date), factor=df2.factor.iloc[::-1].cumprod().iloc[::-1]) if(df1.date.max()<df2.date.max())
                        else df2.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df2.date), factor=df2.factor.iloc[::-1].cumprod().iloc[::-1]).append({'date': pd.to_datetime(df1.date.max()), 'factor': 1}, ignore_index=True),
                    'date',
                    direction='forward')
df3.factor *= df3.qty
df3.rename(columns={'factor': 'factored_qty'}, inplace=True)
```

---

**TIMING for larger dataframes (df1 200 rows, df2 100 rows**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n = 100
np.random.seed(0)
df1_ = pd.DataFrame({'date': [(pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01') - pd.Timedelta(x,'D')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in np.sort(np.random.choice(200*n, 2*n, False))[::-1]],
                    'qty': np.random.randint(1, 20, 2*n)})
df2_ = pd.DataFrame({'date': [(pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01') - pd.Timedelta(x,'D')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in np.sort(np.random.choice(100*n, n, False))[::-1]],
                    'factor': np.random.randint(1, 10, n)})

def setup():
    global df1, df2
    df1 = df1_.copy(True)
    df2 = df2_.copy(True)

def method_apply():
    df1['factored_qty'] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2[df2.date>x.date].factor.prod() * x.qty,axis=1)
    return df1

def method_merge():
    df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df1.date)),
                        df2.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df2.date), factor=df2.factor.iloc[::-1].cumprod().iloc[::-1]) if(df1.date.max()<df2.date.max())
                        else df2.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df2.date), factor=df2.factor.iloc[::-1].cumprod().iloc[::-1]).append({'date': pd.to_datetime(df1.date.max()), 'factor': 1}, ignore_index=True),
                        'date',
                        direction='forward')
    df3.factor *= df3.qty
    df3.rename(columns={'factor': 'factored_qty'}, inplace=True)
    return df3

from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict
def method_dict():
    d = defaultdict(list)
    df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
    df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
    for (date1, qty), (date2, factor) in product(df1.to_numpy(),df2.to_numpy()) : 
        if date1 < date2 : 
            d[(date1, qty)].append(factor)
    outcome = {k:[s,np.prod((s,*v))] for (k,s),v in d.items()}
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(outcome, orient='index', columns=['qty','factored_qty']).reset_index()

def method_numpy():
    mask = df1.date.to_numpy()[:,None] < df2.date.to_numpy()
    it = iter(mask)
    def mul(x):
        val = np.prod(df2.loc[next(it),'factor'])
        return x*val

    df1['factored_qty'] = df1['qty'].map(mul)
    return df1
```

Results:

```
method_apply    220   ms ± 5.99 ms per loop
method_numpy     86.7 ms ± 2.51 ms per loop
method_dict      80.7 ms ± 436 µs per loop
method_merge      8.87 ms ± 68.1 µs per loop
```

Depending on the random factors in df2 their product may lead to an overflow, this was ignored here. `method_dict` only works correctly if the last date in df2 is greater than that of df1, this was also ignored for the timings.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to datetimes :

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
```

Move computation to dictionaries; I'd like to believe computations such as this are faster within dictionaries - it is an assumption; hopefully someone runs tests and proves or debunks this.

```
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
#iterate through data and append factors that meet criteria
for (date1, qty), (date2, factor) in product(df1.to_numpy(),df2.to_numpy()) : 
    if date1 <= date2 : 
        d[(date1, qty)].append(factor)
    else:
        d[(date1, qty)].append(1)
```

Let's see the contents of d:

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {(Timestamp('2016-10-08 00:00:00'), 1): [2, 3],
             (Timestamp('2016-11-08 00:00:00'), 8): [2, 3],
             (Timestamp('2016-12-08 00:00:00'), 2): [1, 3],
             (Timestamp('2017-01-08 00:00:00'), 4): [1, 3]})
```

Get the product of the filtered data with the quantity :

```
outcome = {k:[s,np.prod((s,*v))] for (k,s),v in d.items()}
```

Create dataframe :

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(outcome, orient='index', columns=['qty','factored_qty'])

           qty  factored_qty
2016-10-08  1       6
2016-11-08  8       48
2016-12-08  2       6
2017-01-08  4       12
```

Comment: Added timeit analysis of your answer. it took 1.49ms, stef's 3.65ms and mine 1.31ms. Nice answer though +1.

Comment: thanks for the timing... that was useful information.

Comment: Thank you, I added `_.reset_index` at the end to give a fair comparison. As OP's output also has 3 columns.

Comment: there seems to be a bug in this method in the general case, for instance for `n = 100` `np.random.seed(1)` `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [(pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01') - pd.Timedelta(x,'D')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in np.sort(np.random.choice(200*n, 2*n, False))[::-1]], 'qty': np.random.randint(1, 20, 2*n)})` `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': [(pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01') - pd.Timedelta(x,'D')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in np.sort(np.random.choice(100*n, n, False))[::-1]],'factor': np.random.randint(1, 10, n)})` this method return 194 instead of 200 rows.

Comment: This error depends on the actual data: it occurs if the last date of df2 is less than the last date of df1.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @ stef. I’ll look at it when I am on my PC